# BeautifulSoup: scraping a table by class attribute -- why don't I get any data?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

I'm trying to scrape the ticker symbols located [here](https://investor.vanguard.com/mutual-funds/vanguard-mutual-funds-list) using BeautifulSoup. Currently, I've tried the following:

```
import urllib
import BeautifulSoup
import re

url  = r'https://investor.vanguard.com/mutual-funds/vanguard-mutual-funds-list'
html = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(html)

table = soup.findAll('td', attrs = {'class': re.compile(r'\bticker left\b')})
```

This doesn't, however, give me anything. Can someone explain why I can't get all `td` tags with this `class` attribute? The html would lead one to think this would be possible, and relatively painless. For example:

```
<td class="ticker left">VUSXX              </td>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Continuing my above comment... you can use the following url which returns the required data (obtained from firefox extension Live HTTP Header)

https://api.vanguard.com/rs/ire/02/ind/mf/month-end.jsonp?callback=callback

--

You could also use Selenium which uses Firefox Browser.

1) Install Selneium IDE http://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/

2) Install Selenium Python module https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium

Then u can use the following script.. which will run opens firefox browser.. and gets the results.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup #use bs4 from now on.

browser = webdriver.Firefox()

browser.get('https://investor.vanguard.com/mutual-funds/vanguard-mutual-funds-list')

html = browser.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

mydata = soup.find_all('tr')
```

And, you can find what you want in `mydata`

Answer (score 1):

That is because the page you read is loaded through AJAX dynamically. Hence the read done by Beautiful Soup doesn't capture the AJAX data that is loaded a little while later dynamically.
You could use Mechanize (browser in Python) and BeautifulSoup to do that.

Or, you could copy the data of the HTML page after AJAX call is made and then parse it using BeautifulSoup.

Comment: Can you explain this latter point? Do you mean to save the data to a text file?

Also, how did you know it is loaded through AJAX dynamically?

Comment: Yes, saving the data to a text file. I just printed out the html variable in the code and it didn't have any of the table data, then visited the page, the data was loaded after the loading gif was over.

Comment: This URL https://api.vanguard.com/rs/ire/02/ind/mf/month-end.jsonp?callback=callback  has ALL the required data (EVERYTHING) in I think json format. I come to find the url through Firefox Extension Live HTTP Header (capture the activity) and found the above URL.